# Xamarin - How to create a layout that will adjust its size across all devices while maintaining its ratio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, layout, constraints, frame

I am essentially creating a trading card that must maintain a 2.5x3.5 ratio.
I created the cards background image (with logo's and things that will never change)

I need to create a layout/frame/whatever that will maintain a 2.5x3.5 ratio so I can give it this background image (or image aspectfit) that will never stretch, given that the layouts aspect ratio should never change. This way no matter the size of a phones screen, the height and width size will adjust to fit in any size screen, but the view's aspect will always remain in tact...

The idea is, I will then place labels into this card through Xamarin forms using an API. Name, image, details, etc...

The image of the cards logos will never change, hence the background image, but the labels will change according to character...

Any ideas?

Comment: For a fixed ratio, an image with [Aspect="AspectFit"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#display-images) could help. My concern is that if the image becomes larger on a bigger screen and the label or text remain the same size, does that matter?

Comment: Yeah that's actually what I am doing now, which explains the reason why the text is not staying in the right spot. I would have to figure out how to adjust font according to layout size aswell

Comment: Logically, I was thinking maybe adjust the layouts height according to a percentage of its own width. (Or visa vera)... But then I would still have the issue with fonts not working

Comment: Search dynamically fontsize for help, if you REALLY need a dynamic size view.